# Borel-Catelli - convergence

Tags: probability, random-variables, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $(X_n)$ be an sequence of independent and identically distributed random
variables and $E|X_1|=\infty$. Show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{Xn}{n} $$ = \infty$ almost surely.

I think that I have to use Borel-Cantelli.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is clearly wrong for non-positive $X_n$ (or $X_n$ with bounded positive part).

---

If the $X_n$ are non-negative, however, the claim follows from
$$ P(X_n\ge nC \text{ for infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$})=1 \quad \text{for all $C>0$.}$$
This statement can in fact be proved via Borel-Cantelli by showing that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n\ge nC) = \infty,$$
but $P(X_n\ge nC)=P(X_1/C\ge n)$, so this sum converges if and only if $E(X_1/C)<\infty$.

---

We have thus effectively proved that under your general assumptions
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|X_n|}{n}=\infty \quad \text{$P$-almost surely}.$$

---

By the way: Writing $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^nX_n$, it is easy to deduce from this that also
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|S_n|}{n}=\infty \quad \text{$P$-almost surely},$$
since
$$ \frac{|X_n|}{n}=\frac{|S_n-S_{n-1}|}{n}\le \frac{|S_n|}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{|S_{n-1}|}{n-1}.$$

Comment: Why did you write this: P(Xn≥nC)=P(X1/C≥n)?

Comment: Divide by $C$ and use that the $X_n$ are identically distributed.

Comment: okey and can you explain me next words: so this sum converges if and only if E(X1/C)<∞. I'm sorry but my national language isn't English so I have trouble to understand everything :/

Comment: Don't worry about your English and feel free to keep asking. :-) I used the following general property: $E(|X|)<\infty$ $\iff$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X|\ge n)<\infty$.

Comment: okey i understand :D Do you know how to prove this property ? I need know every detail in this proof

Comment: Does this property work for all Xn or only for discrete?

Comment: It works for all real valued $X_n$. Don't have time right now to explain how. Sorry.